# Регулярное выражение чтобы вытащить текст из HTML кода страницы (без текста ссылок)

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Дано - любая рандомная страница сайта. С помощью парсинга извлекаю её полный HTML-код.
Далее с помощью регулярного выражения нужно получить только текст страницы (без текстов ссылок). То есть регулярное выражение должно полностью очистить HTML оставив только текст (при этом текста ссылок в нем быть не должно). Подскажите, может кто уже сталкивался с такой регуляркой?

Comment: Регулярные выражения [не подходят](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454) для парсинга HTML, есть ли у вас возможность для своей задачи использовать HTML-парсер? [Укажите](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1503522/edit) в метках язык программирования.

Comment: HTML страницы я получаю с помощью парсера. А потом уже полученный HTML-код мне нужно отдельно очистить с помощью регулярного выражения.

Comment: Я считаю, стоит посмотреть в сторону использования возможностей HTML-парсера, который вы используете.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно вам поможет этот код. Сначала удаляем теги `<a>` с содержимым, потом удаляем открывающие и закрывающие теги без содержимого

```
let html = `
<html>
  <body>
  <p class="class">some <span>text</span></p>
  <a href="site.som">link text</a>
  <div>
    <h1>hdhdh</br>hdhd</h1>
  </div>
  <a>lol</a>
  </body>
</html>`

//delete links
const linkRe = /<a\s?[^\>]*>.*<\/a>/g
html = html.replace(linkRe, "")

//delete open tags
const openTagRe = /<\w+[^\>]*>/g
html = html.replace(openTagRe, "")

//delete close tags
const closeTagRe = /<\/[^\>]*>/g
html = html.replace(closeTagRe, "")

console.log(html)
```

Comment: Это JavaScript, если что